# How to extract two specific patterns before another specific pattern using R?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I am trying to extract both a letter (should be K or Y) and all digits between that letter and the pattern `(XO44_TMT6)` and put extracted values in two separate columns (`Mod.residue` and `Mod.position.in.pep`), but failed to get what I want.

Below are my codes and data frame. Can anyone explain why my codes failed and how to fix that?

Thanks so much!

My data frame:

```
structure(list(Modifications = c("Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "Y9(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "Y9(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6); M9(Oxidation)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6); M8(Oxidation)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6); M8(Oxidation)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6); C9(Carbamidomethyl); C18(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y6(XO44_TMT6); C23(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6); C12(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y6(XO44_TMT6); C12(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y6(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y5(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6); C29(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y4(XO44_TMT6); C13(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y4(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y4(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6); M5(Oxidation)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6); C11(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", "Y3(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y29(XO44_TMT6)", "Y25(XO44_TMT6)", "Y25(XO44_TMT6)", "Y25(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y23(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y22(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", "Y22(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y21(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y20(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y20(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6); C8(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6); C19(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y2(XO44_TMT6)", "Y19(XO44_TMT6)", "Y19(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y19(XO44_TMT6)", "Y19(XO44_TMT6)", "Y19(XO44_TMT6)", "Y18(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y18(XO44_TMT6)", "Y18(XO44_TMT6)", "Y18(XO44_TMT6)", "Y18(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y18(XO44_TMT6)", "Y18(XO44_TMT6)", "Y17(XO44_TMT6)", "Y17(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y17(XO44_TMT6)", "Y17(XO44_TMT6)", "Y17(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y16(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y16(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6); C16(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", "Y15(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y14(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y14(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y14(XO44_TMT6)", "Y14(XO44_TMT6)", "Y14(XO44_TMT6)", "Y13(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y13(XO44_TMT6)", "Y13(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6); C14(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", "Y12(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y11(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y11(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y10(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6); C9(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6); C15(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6); C11(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6); C11(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6); C11(Carbamidomethyl)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "Y1(XO44_TMT6)", 
"Y1(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y9(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y9(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y9(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6); C17(Carbamidomethyl)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); Y7(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss+Acetyl); K4(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss); Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss); Y8(XO44_TMT6)", "N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss); Y8(XO44_TMT6)", 
"N-Term(Prot)(Met-loss); Y8(XO44_TMT6)"), Mod.residue = c("9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
"8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "9", "5", 
"5", "5", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
"8", "8", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "8", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "4", "8", "8", "8", "8"
), Mod.position.in.pep = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = "data.frame")
```

My codes:

```
df <- df.test %>% 
  mutate(Mod.residue = gsub(".*(\\w{1})\\d*\\(XO44_TMT6)\\;*\\s*.*", "\\1", Modifications),
         Mod.position.in.pep = gsub(".*\\w{1}(\\d*)\\(XO44_TMT6\\)\\;*\\s*.*", "\\1", Modifications)
           )
```

Comment: I just realised I already answered a (different) question of yours regarding separation/concatenation of text across columns. I strongly recommend you get a good grip of the AWESOME `tidyr` package:
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/

For string manipulation, I also think `stringr` is much more consistent and easier to use than base R functions:
https://stringr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Thanks so much for the recommendation! Will learn how to use `tidyr` package.

Comment: I just posted a follow-up, similar question to see if somone comes up with something better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095697/extract-all-matches-of-a-pattern-and-concatenate-output-with-mutate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are looking for `tidyr::extract`, which fits perfectly for your purpose in a single function call.

```
library(tidyr)

output_extract<-df %>%
        extract(Modifications,
               into = c('Mod.residue', 'Mod.position.in.pep'),
               regex = ".*([A-Z])(\\d+)(?=\\(XO44_TMT6\\)).*",
               remove=FALSE)
```

If you want to keep using `gsub`, you can do it like this (same pattern, two different replacements(`\\1` and `\\2`):

```
output_gsub<-df %>% mutate(Mod.residue=gsub(".*([A-Z])(\\d+)(\\(XO44_TMT6\\)).*", "\\1", Modifications),
              Mod.position.in.pep=gsub(".*([A-Z])(\\d+)(\\(XO44_TMT6\\)).*", "\\2", Modifications))
```

These methods give the same outputs:

```
identical(output_extract, output_gsub)

[1] TRUE
```

You may want to convert the "Mod.position.in.pep" variable to numeric with `as.numeric` afterwards.

Unique values for the output columns:

```
$Mod.residue
[1] "Y" "K"

$Mod.position.in.pep
 [1] "9"  "8"  "7"  "6"  "5"  "4"  "3"  "29" "25" "23" "22" "21" "20" "2"  "19" "18" "17" "16" "15" "14" "13" "12" "11" "10" "1"
```

**EDIT**

This will only work whe there is a single match for "Mod.residue" or "Mod.position.in.pep".

If you have multiple "`[KY]digit(XO44_TMT6)`" per observation, you may have to take a more complex approach, with `mutate %>% unnest_wider %>% unite`

```
#Example data
df<-tibble(Modifications="K4(XO44_TMT6); Y6(XO44_TMT6)")

#solution
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(Mod.residue=str_extract_all(Modifications, "[A-Z]+(?=\\d+\\(XO44_TMT6\\))"),
              Mod.position.in.pep=str_extract_all(Modifications, "\\d+(?=\\(XO44_TMT6\\))"))%>%
        unnest_wider(col='Mod.residue', names_sep = "_")%>%
        unnest_wider(col='Mod.position.in.pep', names_sep = "_")%>%
        unite(starts_with('Mod.residue'), col="Mod.residue", sep = ';', remove=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)%>%
        unite(starts_with('Mod.position'), col='Mod.position.in.pep', sep=';', remove=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Modifications                Mod.residue Mod.position.in.pep
  <chr>                        <chr>       <chr>              
1 K4(XO44_TMT6); Y6(XO44_TMT6) K;Y         4;6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your codes work if e.g., `Y2(XO44_TMT6)` is before `C19(Carbamidomethyl);`  but won't work in the case of `C19(Carbamidomethyl); Y2(XO44_TMT6)`. Easy to fix though.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to extract what I want with `gsub`?

Comment: Got the regex right for gsub. Updated. Working on `extract`

Comment: `extract` is now fine too, @Dr. ChemBio

Comment: Sorry, one more question! If there is more than 1 match, how to get all with `extract`? Thanks

Comment: With extract, you must define N groups to match with the regex, and N columns to spread the output. If you have z matches, the argument `into` should be length z.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "more than one match issue"

Comment: like in the case of `K4(XO44_TMT6); Y6(XO44_TMT6)`, with the above codes only `Y` and `6` go to the 'Mod.residue' and 'Mod.position.in.pep', respectively. Is it possible to extract "K;Y" and "4;6" into the corresponding columns?

Comment: hum, this is tricky. I would suggest looking into methods to split strings into rows:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608726/convert-numbers-in-comma-separated-string-within-a-data-table-column-into-a-long

before the `extract` step

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446921/split-a-string-in-each-row-and-duplicate-that-row

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401505/splitting-a-string-into-new-rows-in-r

Comment: Found a solution for your multiple matches:

Comment: I edited to include an answer to your dual-observations-per-value-example

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate your help! One more question though. Now running the edited codes generate a new issue: e.g., it will generate something like `Y;NA` and '8;NA' when there is a single match.

Comment: You have to add a `na.rm=TRUE` argument to `unite()` updated

Answer (score 2):

I would first create a column in which the whole residue inscl. the position is extracted. Then you can separate the name and the position based on this column and remove the intermediate result afterwards:

```
df.test %>% 
  mutate(
    residue = Modifications %>% str_extract("[KY][0-9]+"),
    Mod.residue = residue %>% str_extract("^[KY]"),
    Mod.position.in.pep = residue %>% str_extract("[0-9]") %>% as.numeric(),
  ) %>%
  select(-residue)
```

`str_extract` is designed to work with the other tidyverse functions.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how to extract what I want with `gsub`?

Comment: `gsub` is for substitution and not for extracting strings.